# Problem in Internet Explorer when Email link is opened in outlook

Tags: configuration

When I press the Email link in the sharepoint site, Outlook is getting opened normally but the original site URL is getting changed to mailto:xxxxxx@xxxx.com and the message "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" is getting displayed on the page in IE

Comment: Are there some more (configuration) details? In which case do you mean? I have here the personal contact because of combination with Lync: no problem. In document library "E-mail a Link": no problem. In wild web page (no sharepoint): mailto: no problem.

Comment: The problem is only for me, might be some settings in IE8. How to know which setting to change?

Comment: I have no idea. But maybe you have a patient colleague where evereything works fine and go through step by step? If not, save your current setting (by screenshot etc) and try defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ie8 has a problem with the links being to long, links less than 512 characters would work fine!

You can see the link by going to F12 develooper or Ie developer Tools and click on the mouse curser, then click on the url link.... you should be able to see the link like so:

```
<a id="Help" href="mailto:thisisanemail@domain.com">Hi click to email me</a>
```

for more info look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241274/mailto-fails-in-ie-where-there-is-a-long-body-text-is-there-any-way-to-resolve